# Rails 6 undefined local variable or method `private' for #<Pdf:0x00007fc3b0285930> Did you mean? print

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

hi all iam new to rails , iam trying to upload pdf and i worte a create and validate function only to accept pdfs but after i click submit it throws this error :

error:

undefined local variable or method `private' for #Pdf:0x00007fc3b0285930 Did you mean? print

my controller.rb
class Pdf < ApplicationRecord

```
  after_commit :attachment1
  #after_commit(on: %i[ create update ]) { attachment_changes.delete(name.to_s).try(:upload) }



    has_one_attached :attachment

    validates :attachment, presence: true, blob: { content_type: ['application/pdf']  }
  #validates :attachment, attached: true, size: { less_than: 1.megabytes , message: 'PDF should be less than 1MB' }


  def attachment1
    attachment_path = "#{Dir.tmpdir}/#{attachment.filename}"
      File.open(attachment_path, 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(attachment.download)
  end   

  private

    def check_file_type
      if attachment.attached? && !attachment.content_type.in?(%w(application/msword application/pdf))
          errors.add(:attachment, 'Must be a PDF or a DOC file')
      end
    end

  end

end
```

controller :

```
class PdfsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pdf = Pdf.new
  end

  def create
      @pdf = Pdf.new(pdf_params)

      if @pdf.save
        redirect_to @pdf, notice: 'Pdf was successfully uploaded.'
      else
        render 'new' 
      end
  end
  
 # def create
 #    @pdf = Pdf.new(pdf_params)
 #    if @pdf.save
 #      #notice: 'Pdf was successfully uploaded'
 #      notice: 'Pdf was successfully uploaded.'
 #    else
 #      redirect_to new_pdf_path
 #    end
 #      redirect_to pdfs_path
 # end

  private
    def set_pdf
      @pdf = Pdf.find(params[:id])
    end

    def pdf_params
      params.require(:pdf).permit(:attachment)
    end
end
```

form :

```
<%= form_for Pdf.new do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

but the file is getting uploaded to the temp dir but i cant validate the size and it should return me "PDF was uploaded" after submit

Comment: You're missing an `end` before the private keyword in the Pdf class.

Comment: hanks do you how to validate size with active storage ? i want to upload only files below 1 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blocks are misaligned.

`File.open(attachment_path, 'wb') do |file|`

is where the issues start, that should have it's own `end` but the end that it uses is the one that that *appears* to be for the `attachment1` method. This means that the `private` is actually being treated as a method within the `attachment1` method.

Comment: thanks do you how to validate size with active storage ? i want to upload only files below 1 MB

Comment: i tried like this but not working   #validates :attachment, attached: true, size: { less_than: 1.megabytes , message: 'PDF should be less than 1MB' }

Comment: @Callum Recommend you create a separate question for that, if you haven't already and it's still an issue